# Apex REST Endpoint and connection within a single organization

Tags: apex, json, rest

I try to make bootstrap table with server-side pagination. That's why I created this REST service:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Test/*')
global with sharing class Test{

 @HttpGet
 global static String doGet() {
    Room r = new Room();
    r.id = 0;
    r.name = 'Item 0';
    r.price= '$0';

    List<Room> r1 = new List<Room>();
    r1.add(r);

    return JSON.serialize(r1);
}


public class Room{
    public Integer id{get;set;}
    public String name{get;set;}
    public String price{get;set;}
}
}
```

then I'm trying to consume this rest in bootstrap table

```
<table id="table"
           data-toggle="table"
           data-url="/services/apexrest/Test/"
           data-height="400"
           data-side-pagination="server"
           data-pagination="true"
           data-page-list="[5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200]"
           data-search="true">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
            <th data-field="id">ID</th>
            <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
            <th data-field="price">Item Price</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

Unfortunately, when I try to display the data, I get an error (401 UNAUTHORIZED). So how can I authenticate? I do all queries within one organization. Unfortunately, I browsed the internet, but can't find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the Authorization header. You haven't specified exactly how your module works, but you basically need to set the Authorization header to the following value:

```
var authHeader = "OAuth {!$Api.Session_ID}";
req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", authHeader);
```

Comment: look on m answer

Answer (score 0):

I try to consume REST according to your advice:

```
  $(function() {
         var authHeader = "OAuth {!$Api.Session_ID}";
         sforce.connection.init('{!$Api.Session_ID}', '/services/apexrest/Test/'); 


        sforce.connection.remoteFunction({
            url : "/services/apexrest/Test/",
            requestHeaders: {
                "Authorization": authHeader,
                "Content-Type":"application/json", 
                "Connection":"Keep-Alive" 
            },
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            onSuccess : function(response) {
                  console.log("Success " +response);  
               },
           onFailure : function(response) {
                  console.log("Failed " + response)
              }
       });    
       });
```

but console show me that error:

> Failed    Error 400 Unable to
>   forward request due to: no protocol: /services/apexrest/Test/
>
> ### HTTP ERROR 400
>
> Problem accessing
>   /services/proxy. Reason:
>
> ```
>     Unable to forward request due to: no
> protocol: /services/apexrest/Test/
> ```
>
> ---
>
> *Powered
>   by Jetty://*

Comment: your URL should be

"https : //cs2.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Test/"

where cs2 denotes your insatnce url